# How to create rows dynamically in excel based on list of strings in a cell

Tags: excel, vba

I have two sheets in my .xlsx file. I want to create a list of strings on one sheet and dynamically create a list of rows on the other sheet with the corresponding information.

For example, let say that I have a list of types of buildings and the tasks to model, gather materials, and construct the building are the same, its just the same set of tasks repeated with the building types.

Sheet 1:

[image: Sheet with the list of types in cell]

Sheet 2:

[image: Sheet with the list of tasks to be built from values in cell from sheet one]

This is a simplified explanation of what I would like to accomplish. I dont know if macros will be required for this or not.

Comment: Loops, one to go through the result of the `Split()` function and the second to go through an array of the tasks.

Answer (score 1):

### Solution without VBA

Use Text to columns with a space delimiter on Sheet1 Cell B1
Then in B2 enter the formula:

```
=INDEX(Sheet2!$A$2:$A$10, MATCH(0, COUNTIF($B$1:B1, Sheet2!$A$2:$A$10)*FIND(B$1,Sheet2!$A$2:$A$10), 0))
```

And enter with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> as this is an array formula. Then drag across your 3 columns and down

This will give you 3 unique lists containing any cell that partially contains one of your headers values

[image: results]